# find the $\text{Min}(f)=?$

Tags: calculus

> let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{k-x}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k-x}} \ \ : k \in  \mathbb{R^+}$
>
> then find the $\text{Min}(f)=?$

Comment: If $k \leqslant 6$, the minimum is $f\left( \frac{k}{2} \right)$. If $k > 6$, the minimum reaches at two points and the expression gets really messy.

Comment: Write $k:=2a^2$ with $a>0$ and $x:=a^2(1+y)$ and arrive at
$$g(y):=a\bigl(\sqrt{1-y}+\sqrt{1+y}\bigr)+{1\over a}\left({1\over\sqrt{1-y}}+{1\over\sqrt{1+y}}\right)\qquad(-1\leq y\leq 1)\ .$$
It is sufficient to consider the interval $0\leq y\leq 1$. Parametrize this interval by
$$y:=2\sqrt{(1-z)z}\qquad\left(0\leq z\leq{1\over2}\right)\ .$$ This gives
$$\sqrt{1-y}=\sqrt{1-z}-\sqrt{z}, \quad \sqrt{1+y}=\sqrt{1-z}+\sqrt{z},\quad \sqrt{1-y}\>\sqrt{1+y}=1-2z\ .$$ (Rest in the next comment)

Comment: It follows that $g$ can be replaced by
$$h(z)={2\over a}\sqrt{1-z}\left(a^2+{1\over 1-2z}\right)\qquad\left(0\leq z\leq{1\over2}\right)\ .$$
If $a\leq\sqrt{3}$ this is minimal when $z=0$, and if $a>\sqrt{3}$ this is minimal when $z={1\over 2}-{1+\sqrt{8a^2+1}\over4a^2}$. In the second case the minimal value seems to be an ugly function of $a$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter why $a\leq \sqrt{3}$ minimal when $z=0$ and also why $a>\sqrt{3}$ ...

Comment: @ChristianBlatter and when $-1<y<0$ what ?

Comment: (i) Differentiate the function $h$, and you will find out. (ii) The function $g$ is an even function of $y$; therefore we only need to consider $0\leq y<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is defined for $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{R}, 0<x<k\}$ and that you want a global minimum over all $k$.

Note that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$. Thus, by AM-GM, $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{k-x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-x}}}{4} \geq \sqrt[4]{1} = 1$, so $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{k-x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k-x}}\geq 4$. Therefore, the minimum value of $f$ is $4$, with equality at $\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{k-x}$, so $x=1$, $k=2$.

For specific values of $k$, there is no clean way I can see to do it, but from Wolfram Alpha, we get some interesting results. For $0 < k \leq 6$, we have the only minimum occurring at $x=\frac{k}{2}$, giving $f(x)=\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}}$. However, for $k > 6$, we have the minima occuring at $x=\frac{k}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k^2-4k-2\sqrt{4k+1}-2}$. The corresponding values for $f$ is too convoluted for me to calculate. :P

Comment: It's not always true that $f'(x) < 0$ for $0 < x < \frac{k}{2}$, e.g when $k = 10$.

Comment: Huh, should've checked on paper. Thanks.